# What is replacement of include_once and require_once MEQP1 standard

Tags: magento-1, coding-standards

Got these WARNINGS how can I resolve it ?

> "include_once" statement detected. File manipulations are discouraged.
>   Concatenating is forbidden.
>
> "require_once" statement detected. File manipulations are discouraged.
>   Concatenating is forbidden.

Code

```
include_once BP.DS.'app'.DS.'code'.DS.'core'.DS.'Mage'.DS.'Catalog'.DS.'Model'.DS.'Resource'.DS.'Attribute.php';
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism updated the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need such `include_once` in your code.

If the code you're using is in the scope of the Magento software, you can simply do the following whenever you need to deal with that class:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/attribute');
```

Comment: check this example of override http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Comment: @QaisarSatti well it is totally different than what you are doing right ? In this example, it's about controller rewrite. In your case, you include a resource model.

Comment: i know but i can't change it.Is there is any alternative of include_once or require function in magneto?

Comment: @QaisarSatti why can't you ? in your case, the change is easy as I explained in my answer